# Properly wrapping text in a list

Tags: css, list

I am having a problem trying to get the text in a list item wrapped to the next line to display properly. It's the first menu item. I've checked many of the other related answers but the answers don't seem to fit my situation.

[image: This is what it looks like now]

```
#menuSide ul {
  margin-left: -45px;
  text-indent: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menuSide li {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00136F;
}

#menuSide a, #menuSide a:visited {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana,Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#menuSide a:hover {
  color: #3B5998;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#menuSide .here {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
}



<ul>
<?php
if ($thisPage=='speaking') {
  echo '<li><span class="here">&raquo;&nbsp;&nbsp;Speaking Engagements in Jerusalem</span>';
}
else {
  echo '<li><a href="/speaking.php">Speaking Engagements in Jerusalem</a>    </li>';
}?>

<?php
if ($thisPage=='events') {
  echo '<li><span class="here">&raquo;&nbsp;&nbsp;Recent Events</span>';
}
else {
  echo '<li><a href="/events/index.php">Recent Events</a></li>';
}?>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your PHP code, your first <li> element inside the if doesn't have its closing tag (</li>) is that all you code? it could be that.

Comment: You may be having issues due to the fixed height declaration on your `#menuSide a` elements. This will prevent a double lined link from taking up the appropriate space. Try `line-height`instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `height: 1.2em;` from `#menuSide a, #menuSide a:visited` will help. By setting 1.2em height for element you fix its height at 120% of a single line of inner text height. That's why the second line doesn't fit. Try to use `line-height` or `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` instead.

P.S.: you've forgotten closing `</li>` tags here:

```
if ($thisPage=='speaking') {
  echo '<li><span class="here">&raquo;&nbsp;&nbsp;Speaking Engagements in Jerusalem</span>';
}
```

and here:

```
if ($thisPage=='events') {
  echo '<li><span class="here">&raquo;&nbsp;&nbsp;Recent Events</span>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Now I just need to figure out how to make the text in the second line of the first list item line up with the first line (or even indented a bit more).

Comment: @Lee, I don't know what for, but you use `text-indent` that specifies the indentation of the **first line** of text in a block container. Apparently, that's the source of your new problem. To fix it, remove `text-indent: 15px;` from `#menuSide ul` and set `padding-right` and `padding-left` properties for `#menuSide li` (or for `#menuSide ul` depending on your page's style needs).

Comment: I was using the 'text-indent' to move the list item from the left margin. So I removed it and added the following to each style.

    #menuSide ul   
    padding-left: 3em;
#menuSide li {
padding-left: 20px;
}


Now it now works fine! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lee, you're welcome. You should use `text-indent` only there it's needed. At `<p>` for example. Paddings and margins are more suitable for such things as `<li>` tag.

Comment: @Lee, if my answer is full and your problem is solved, you can mark my answer as accepted to show that the question is answered and to say me thanks. :)